# Emulator Does Not Close Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, emulation

Has anyone else noticed this in ubuntu (or possible any other linux environment)? Clicking the X does not close the emulator. I have to manually use the system monitor to kill the process everytime I use it.

Comment: I dont know if this helps: maybe you created a SD image equal or superior than 2gb, so delete this virtual device and do another one of 1.5gb or else.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use Genymotion instead of the included emulator, as it is significantly faster, and in all likelihood more stable.

Other than that, I agree with the previous user that it would be worthwhile to try removing the virtual device and creating a new virtual device with 1.5 GB of memory.